# iOS remove clear bar under the keyboard

Tags: ios, user-interface, keyboard

The question I have is that when the keyboard comes up, there is a small clear bar that appears under it. I've tried checking this in various other programs and it holds true there as well, except safari. Is there any way to either remove this bar and extend the keyboard itself or at least recolor the bar so that it blends in?

I just don't like the feel of how it is done.

**Update**
I have included the picture of the keyboard in the calendar app where it shows the clear area.

[image]

Comment: Would you post a screen capture of this clear bar?

Comment: I've updated with the screen capture. As you can see the keyboard doesn't extend all the way down and shows the calendar behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a user controlled setting: you can move the keyboard up and down by holding down on the "hide keyboard" button then dragging. You've probably done that by accident and the iPad has remembered your setting.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me. Not exactly sure how this happened, but it is good to now know how to disable it.